# can I run socketio swift without a dedicated port on server

Tags: swift, socket.io

I have used this simple **SocketIOManager** class to connect with server

```
static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://192.168.31.57:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func establishConnection() {
    manager.defaultSocket.connect()
}


func closeConnection() {
    manager.defaultSocket.disconnect()
}
```

Here the **IP** is my local host **IP** and the **port** I am listening is defined on a **node.js** file which I have downloaded from internet. Its working fine and its connecting as intended. however in my real life project I am trying to connect to out server and my api team didnt give me any specific **port** to listen, they just gave me the **url**. Needless to say I could not establish a socket connection with the server. My question is can I establish a socket connection without a listening to a specific port? This is my first project with socket programming and I found very few tutorial on the internet about socket programming in iOS. I am using **socket.io-client-swift** library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In socket base connection, port is much required.

A socket is one endpoint of a two-way communication link between two programs running on the network. A socket is bound to a port number so that the TCP layer can identify the application that data is destined to be sent to.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html